# Как удалить связь many to many в symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

У меня есть такая таблица, которая создалась автоматически из за join-a user_post(user_id, post_id);

Сам join:

```
 /**
 * @var Collection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Post")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_post",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $posts;
```

Как мне удалить запись в таблице user_post, когда ставиться у post или user deleted_at?

Comment: И сразу вопрос - а зачем ее удалять? Если у тебя удален пост или юзер, то джойн не найдет этих данных. Но если все-таки надо удалять - то либо листенером\сабскрайбером, либо если deleted_at юзается через какой-нибудь Gedmo\SoftDeleteable или подобную либу, то смотреть как в либе это реализовано.

Comment: Сделай миграцию повесь на оба поле user.id -> foreingId('user_id')->onDelete('cascade') и тоже самое с постом и тогда удаление будет каскадное, а если SoftDelete включен у обоих, тогда должен быть где-то event типа deleteCallback, который этим занимается и он может удалить связь. А вообще это связь pivot и можно сделать $this->posts()->detach() и тогда удалятся записи в табличке user_posts